# Parse unstructured data in shell

Tags: linux, shell, parsing, grep

I want to parse the following file:

```
0.9103726 = (MATCH) sum of:
0.0050276485 = (PHRASE) title:abc
0.9323103726 = (MATCH) sum of:
0.1323103726 = (MATCH) mul of:
0.185 = (PHRASE) title:xyz
0.9103726 = (MATCH) sum of:
0.234 = (PHRASE) title:bcd
```

My desired output is like:

```
0.0050276485 -- title -- abc
0.185 -- title -- xyz
0.234 -- title -- bcd
```

The command I have tried is like this:

```
grep -oP '[\d.]+(?==(PHRASE)title:?)'
```

But it is not giving me proper output. 
Sorry for the earlier question. It was not clear.

Comment: The reason your regex doesn't work is that parentheses don't match themselves in Perl regular expressions; use `\(PHRASE\)` to match the parenthesized expression literally.  In addition, you need a space before `title:` in order for it to match.  But in the end, `grep` can't parse anything, just print the line or substring which matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is the first element before `=` and the last one after `:`, then say:

```
$ awk -F"=|:" -v OFS="--" '{print $1, $NF}' file
x --y 
x1--y1
```

Note we also tell `awk` to use `--` as the output field separator.

Since you did not post any of your attempts, showing the output in the same line is left as an exercise :)

---

### Update from updated question

Similarly, you can use this:

```
$ awk -F"=|:| " -v OFS="--" '/title/{print $1, $(NF-1), $NF}' a
0.0050276485--title--abc
0.185--title--xyz
0.234--title--bcd
```

This does the same as before, only that just for the lines containing `title`. On these, it prints the first, penultimate and last fields based on either `=`, `:` or  (space) separators.

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention my attempts and full content of my file. 
My file can have anydata.
I have to find the above pattern(x=(PHRASE) title:y) that'y I can't use AWK.
Here is the command I fired : grep -oP '[\d.]+(?==\(PHRASE\)title\:?)'

Comment: Why can't you use `awk`? Update your question with all these details. Note the code is difficult to read in comments, so there it will be way clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi I've updated my answer. Note `grep` is quite unlikely to be able to solve this. `awk` is the way to go, or maybe also `sed`.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi no problem :) It is good to get the right tool for each job! Glad that it worked to you. I am adding some further explanations for the final command.

Answer (score 0):

Sed version

```
sed '/PHRASE/!d ;  s/:/\ \-\-\ / ; s/(PHRASE)/\-\-/' data
```

Or

```
sed 's/:/\ \-\-\ / ; /(PHRASE)/!d ; s//\-\-/' data
```

Comment: It would be worth including a brief explanation of how your sed script achieves what the original poster was needing. Thanks.